# Powershell Invoke-VMScript to run "dpkg --configure" in Debian on VMware Issue

Tags: powershell, debian, vmware

I cannot run this command "dpkg --configure -a" through powershell script on VMware Debian .
Other commands work.
I have tried many ways, but it was unsuccessful.
The command can be run manually on VMware Debian.

Debian 5.10
PowerShell 7.4.0

Below is my command:

```
    `Invoke-VMScript -VM $guestHost -ScriptText "dpkg --configure -a" -GuestUser $guestUser -GuestPassword $guestPass -ScriptType Bash`
```

I got the error message:

`Invoke-VMScript: 12/28/2023 9:44:29 PM  Invoke-VMScript         Index was outside the bounds of the array`

Have any idea for the isssue ?

I have tried throw to background task, but it is the same result.

Comment: Are you running the command with the back ticks at the beginning/end or did you add those for this post? What's the value of `$guestHost` (string, VirtualMachine object, etc)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve].